# R MICE imputation not imputing all variables

Tags: r, r-mice

I have a dataset with many variables. All of them are formatted appropriately(numeric, factors and dates). I want to impute 3 factor variables and 15 numeric variables.

I have written following code to know about the variable's relative position in the dataset.

```
numbered_list <- ls(data)
```

Then, I want to impute my factor variable using random forest and numeric variables using predictive mean matching. For which, I have written my code to impute as:

```
imp_data <- mice(data, m = 5, method=c("rf"
                                    , ""
                                    , ""
                                    , ""
                                    , "pmm"
                                    , ""
                                    , ""
                                    , ""
                                    , ""
                                    , ""
                                    , ""
                                    , ""
                                    , ""
                                    , ""
                                    , "pmm"
                                    , "pmm"
                                    , "pmm"
                                    , "pmm"
                                    , "pmm"
                                    , "pmm"
                                    , "pmm"
                                    , "pmm"
                                    , "pmm"
                                    , "pmm"
                                    , "pmm"
                                    , "pmm"
                                    , "pmm"
                                    , "pmm"
                                    , ""
                                    , ""
                                    , ""
                                    , ""
                                    , "rf"
                                    , ""
                                    , "rf"
                                    , ""
                                    , ""), maxit = 20)
```

The issue is only my first variable is being imputed and the rest are ignored. R displays warning message at the end stating 'number of logged events: 102' but I'm unsure how to check them.

My question is: What is the MICE package looking for that I'm missing? and how can I solve this?

The actual data cannot be shared and I tried to recreate the issue with fake data but was unsuccessful.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can check the logged events by `imp_data$loggedEvents`, although it usually takes some deciphering to figure out what they actually mean. It's difficult to give specific advice without knowing the data, but it probably wouldn't hurt to specify the imputation models more directly. IE, try supplying a `predictorMatrix` to limit which variables are used in which models.

Comment: Thanks, I supplied the predictorMatrix and it solved it.